# Can GlassFish 2 be configured to make a webservice accessible **only** from some specific port?

Tags: web-services, configuration, glassfish

Currently we serve some web applications in a domain on port 80. This port is accessible from the internet.

Now there should be deployed some EJB wich expose some of their methods as webservices using the @WebMethod annotation. These should not be accessibe from the (public) port 80, but only from port 8000, which can be accessed only from the internal network.

I set up a new virtual server named "internal" which uses a http-listener that listens on port 8000:

```
<virtual-server hosts="${com.sun.aas.hostName}" http-listeners="http-listener-3" id="internal" log-file="${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/server.log" state="on">
          <property name="sso-enabled" value="false"/>
          <property name="docroot" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/docroot"/>
          <property name="accesslog" value="${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/access"/>
</virtual-server>

<http-listener acceptor-threads="1" address="0.0.0.0" blocking-enabled="false" default-virtual-server="internal" enabled="true" family="inet" id="http-listener-3" port="8000" security-enabled="false" server-name="" xpowered-by="false">
          <property name="proxiedProtocols" value="ws/tcp"/>
</http-listener>
```

Then I assigned this virtual server to the enterprise application that hosts the service by setting the *virtual-servers* attribute.

```
<application-ref disable-timeout-in-minutes="30" enabled="true" lb-enabled="false" ref="myapp" virtual-servers="internal"/>
```

The webservices are available now both on port 80 and 8000, but what is needed is that they are available on port 8000 **only**, not from 80. Is there a way to achieve this in GlassFish 2 using a single domain? Or must a second domain be used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull your webMethods out and place them into their own app. Then when you deploy the app you can manage (the target tab) which server / virtual servers they end up on.

Comment: Do you mean the "target" tab in netbeans?